# Why does my merge commit with no conflicts show up in git log filtered by one folder but not another when it involves both folders?

Tags: git

While working on a tool that determines relevant history for a given commit from a previous export, I found a rather odd behavior in git log and I can't seem to pin down what's happening. I'm hoping someone can help explain the behavior.

I've created the following commit graph, and I have two separate workspaces in the same repo. Workspace A has a single file updated in every single commit listed except for E and I which are simple merges (for example `git merge bar` created commit I).  Workspace B, on the other hand, has only had files changed in commits A and L.

[image]When I run `git log --name-only --oneline -- workspaceA` I get commit 'I' listed, but there are no files affected:

```
b7faf96 (HEAD -\> main) Commit I  
a3c265e Commit H  
workspaceA/H  
e03be40 (bar) Commit L  
workspaceA/L  
7ead348 Commit G  
workspaceA/G  
7b80d8d (tag: workspaceA-2020.0.2.0, baz) Commit B  
workspaceA/B  
d383bfa Commit F  
workspaceA/F  
6d2b8a4 (tag: workspaceB-2020.0.1.0, tag: workspaceA-2020.0.1.0) Commit A  
workspaceA/A  
...
```

Note that this list contains Commit 'I' but it has no files listed under the commit.

Now, when I run `git log --name-only --oneline -- workspaceB` I get a list that doesn't contain commit 'I' at all:

```
e03be40 (bar) Commit L  
workspaceB/L  
6d2b8a4 (tag: workspaceB-2020.0.1.0, tag: workspaceA-2020.0.1.0) Commit A  
workspaceB/A  
...
```

My problem is that there isn't any consistency in whether commit 'I' shows up, even though none of the files were actually changed during the merge which created commit 'I'. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

This doesn't meet my expectations because I can't see why commit 'I' only shows up when filtering for one folder and not the other, even though the merge involves changes to both folders as seen in my screenshot.

Comment: There are several things that interact here: (1) Git doesn't store folders, only files; filtering for a "folder" really means "for any changes detected in files that are in those folders". (2) Merge commits filter weirdly (because they have *two* parents, not just one). Since `I` is a merge commit, never expect anything particularly sensible here. You can make the output less crazy using `-m`, which splits each merge into multiple "virtual commits", each with one parent, but thing are still a little crazy.

Comment: @torek although I agree with your comment, I think there is a logical answer to the question, which I took a stab at answering. My answer works for the scenario described, though, I'm not 100% sure that my explanation of a "new state" fully captures it.

Comment: @TTT: given the way `git log` prunes history by default, I think you've got this one right. Adding `--full-history` or similar may also change the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Git is showing you the list of commits that represent a new *state* from the point of view of the path filter you specified.

From the POV of `workspaceA`, there are changes to something in that folder in **both sides of the merge**. Commit `I` has two parents: `H` and `L`. The `merge-base` of `H` and `L` is commit `B`, and there is at least one change to something in `workspaceA` between `B` and `H`, and also between `B` and `L`. This means that commit `I` has a new state for `workspaceA` even though the commit itself doesn't contain any changes.

Notice this is not the case for `workspaceB`. There are no changes between `B` and `H`, and there is a change between `B` and `L`. So the merge commit `I` will not have a state change compared to `L`, which has already been listed.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `git log` completely hides diffs for merge commits.

Add one of the `diff-merges` options to see what files were considered : I'd advise `--cc`, you may also try `-c` or `-m`.

---

From [git help log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-mergesoffnoneonfirst-parent1separatemcombinedcdense-combinedcc) :

> **DIFF FORMATTING :**
>
> [...]
>
> `--diff-merges=(off|none|on|first-parent|1|separate|m|combined|c|dense-combined|cc)`
>
> Specify diff format to be used for merge commits. Default is `off` unless `--first-parent` is in use, in which case `first-parent` is the default.

Shorthand for options are :

- `-m` for `--diff-merges=on` or `--diff-merges=m`
- `-c` for `combined`
- `--cc` for `dense-combined`